# Is there a way to get the cluster_ip from a service i created using Kubernetes Python Client?

Tags: python, kubernetes

After creating a deployment with Kubernetes Python Client , and exposing the service with type ClusterIP, how can i get the Cluster-IP using the python client instead of using Kubectl command ?

Service was created based on the example code

```
def create_service():
core_v1_api = client.CoreV1Api()
body = client.V1Service(
    api_version="v1",
    kind="Service",
    metadata=client.V1ObjectMeta(
        name="service-example"
    ),
    spec=client.V1ServiceSpec(
        selector={"app": "deployment"},
        ports=[client.V1ServicePort(
            port=5678,
            target_port=5678
        )]
    )
)
# Creation of the Deployment in specified namespace
# (Can replace "default" with a namespace you may have created)
core_v1_api.create_namespaced_service(namespace="default", body=body)
```

There is a command to list pod ips on the documentation

```
v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
print("Listing pods with their IPs:")
ret = v1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(watch=False)
for i in ret.items:
    print("%s\t%s\t%s" %
          (i.status.pod_ip, i.metadata.namespace, i.metadata.name))
```

im wondering if there's a way to do something similar with Cluster-IP from services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply get the service and read its `spec.cluster_ip` property:

```py
from kubernetes import client, config
config.load_kube_config()
api = client.CoreV1Api()
service = api.read_namespaced_service(name="kubernetes", namespace="default")
print(service.spec.cluster_ip)
# 10.100.0.1
```